# An almost Shakespearian alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

Every letter stands for a digit in base-9 representation, 
different letters stand for different digits,
and leading digits are always non-zero.

```
       ALLS
    +  WELL
    +  THAT
    +   END
   ---------
      SWELL
```

Which digit does each letter represent? (Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined.)

Comment: there are 30 solutions -.-

Comment: By base 9 you mean I can use digits 1 to 8 or 9 is allowed, or I'm writing 9 in base 9 as `10` (which would be strange)?

Comment: @Oray Actually, in base 9, I got 2 solutions.

Comment: it was 10 originally :)

Comment: @Oray. So Am I allowed to use the digit 9 or not. Sorry but It's not clear to me so I'm asking bluntly :)

Comment: @Marius the question is not mine but the summation and numbers needs to be base-9, that means letters can be 0-8 and addition must be base-9 as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we see that $S\in\{1,2\}$.  From the first column, we see that $S+L+T+D$ yields $L$.  Thus, $S+T+D\in \{10,20\}$.  Since S is so small, we can conclude that $S+T+D=10$.

From the second column, we see $L+L+A+N$ yields $L$. Since there is a carry over of 1, $L+A+N\in\{8,18\}$.

From the third column, we see $L+E+H+E$ yields $E$.  Since the carry over is 1 or 2, we know $L+E+H\in\{7,8,17,18\}$.

Lastly, $A+W+T$ yields $W$.  Again, carry over is 1 or 2, so $A+T\in\{7,8,17,18\}$.  But only $\{7,8\}$ are really possible, so we know that ***S=1***.

Also, we know that $T+D=8 \implies A+T=7$, so we know that $A=D-1$.  Also, we know the carry over from the 3rd column must be 2, so $L+E+H\in\{17,18\}$.  The possible values are then:

- $A \in \{2,4,5\}$
- $T \in \{5,3,2\}$
- $D \in \{3,5,6\}$

Thus, 5 is not an option for any other letter since it must be used by one of these three.

Lets look at the letter $L\in\{0,2,3,4,6,7,8\}$.

- If $L=0$, then $L+E+H$ cannot be made 17 or 18.
- If $L=2$, then $A+N=6 \implies N=T-1$ which means either $N$ or $A$ must be 2.
- If $L=3$, then $A+N=5 \implies N=T-2 \implies N=0, T=2, A=5, D=6$.  But then $E+H=15$ cannot be made since 6 in taken.
- If $L=4$, then $A+N=4 \implies A=N=2$.  Thus, $A+N=14 \implies A=5, T=2, D=6, N=8$. Again, this makes $E+H=13$ impossible with the remaining digits.
- If $L=8$, then $A+N=10 \implies N=T+2$. Thus, $A=5, T=2, D=6, N=4$. Again, $E+H=8$ is impossible with the remaining digits.
- If $L=7$, then $A+N=11 \implies N=T+3$. Thus, either $A=2,T=5,D=3,N=8$ or $A=4,T=3,D=5,N=6$.  In both cases, $E+H=10$ are impossible.

Thus $L=6$.

So, $A+N=12$ or $A+N=2$.  If $A+N=12$, then $N=T+4$.  Thus, $A=4, T=3, D=5, N=7$. Also, the carry over is 2 so that $L+E+H=17$.  Thus, $E+H=11$ so $E,H \in \{8,2\}$.  This leaves $W=0$, but we cannot have a 3 digit number.

Therefore, $A+N=2$.  Thus, $A=2, N=0, T=5, D=3$.  $L+E+H=18$ so $E+H+12$.  This requires $E,H\in\{4,6\}$.

So the valid solutions are:

```
 2661    
 8466
 5725
+ 403
-----
18466
```

And

```
 2661    
 8766
 5425
+ 703
-----
18766
```

Where:

$$A=2, D=3, L=6, N=0, S=1, T=5, W=8, E,H\in\{4,7\}$$

Answer (score 2):

Solution(s):

> A = 2
>  L = 6
>  S = 1
>  W = 8
>  E = 4/7
>  T = 5
>  H = 7/4
>  N = 0
>  D = 3

Explanation
In order to make it easier my explanation are going to be made in base 10.
So if I say A+W = 10 this means in base 10, In base 9 it would be A+W = 11 (which is 10 in base 9). Headache already? :)
I will only specify base 9 where is needed

> SWELL - WELL = S0000 (in base 9).   this means that
>  
>   ALLS +
>   THAT +
>    END =
>  S0000 (base 9).
>  
>  S has to be 1. In order for it to be 2, A+T+ carriage from the hundreds
>  should be above 18 (20 in base 9). Since they can be max 8+7 it means
>  the carriage from the tens should be 3 at least. And L+H+E can be max
>  6+5+4. You cannot add up to 27 (30 in base 9) by adding the carriage
>  from the units position.
>  
>   ALL1 +
>   THAT +
>    END =
>  10000 (base 9).
>
>    This means T+D = 8. 
>  Also T+A+carriage from hundreds = 9 (10 in base 9). This means T+A = 7
>  or 8. It cannot be 8 because this will result in A = D. So T+A = 7.
>  This results in D = A+1 so D >= 1. But if D = 2 then A = 1 = S so D >=
>  3.   Let's start with D = 3. So A = 2 and T = 5
>  
>   2LL1 +
>   5H25 +
>    EN3 =
>  10000 (base 9)
>
>  this means L + 2 + N +  1 (carriage) = 9 or 18 (base 10). So L + N = 6/15 (base 10).
>  
>  L + N = 6 can be obtained from the remaining digits only if one is 0
>  and one is 6.
>  Let's say L = 6 and N = 0.
>  
>   2661 +
>   5H25 +
>    E03 =
>  10000 (base 9)
>  
>  this means H + 6 + E + 1 (carriage) = 18 (base 10). H + E  = 11 (base
>  10). Only available values for a sum of 12 (base 10) are 7 and 4.
>  Works in both combinations.   but let's say H = 7 and E = 4   Now to
>  the original sum
>  
>   2661 +
>   W466 +
>   5725 +
>    403 =
>  1W466
>  
>  W can be anything but the only available value is 8. 
>  
>  So.   Solution 1
>  
>   2661 +
>   8466 +
>   5725 +
>    403 =
>  18466  (base 9)
>  
>  A = 2   L = 6   S = 1   W = 8   E = 4   T = 5   H = 7   N = 0   D = 3 
>  
>  
>  Solution 2 reversing H and E
>  
>  
>   2661 +
>   8466 +
>   5725 +
>    403 =
>  18466  (base 9)
>  
>  A = 2   L = 6   S = 1   W = 8   E = 7   T = 5   H = 4   N = 0   D = 3 
>  
>  
>  When we started this we assumed D = 3.   Let's increment. D = 4. From
>  T + D = 8 we get a "No go" since T = D = 4.   For D = 5 We get T = 3
>  and A = 4.
>  
>   4LL1 +
>   3H43 +
>    EH5 =
>  10000 (base 9)
>  
>  So L + H + 4 + 1 = 9 or 18 (base 10). L + H = 4 or 13. 
>  
>  So L and H can be 6 and 7.   L = 6 results in
>  
>   4661 +
>   3743 +
>    EN5 =
>  10000 (base 9).
>  
>  This results in N = 7 which cannot be since H = 7.   same goes for L =
>  7 and H = 6.
>  
>  For D = 6 or more we get similar results following the same path.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I'm still new to this "spoiler" blockquotes. I'm working on it.